Blank screen when generate an aab and publish it
I have a problem in my app with maps, so I'm using expo and I'm developing in react-native, I integrated my application with Google maps. When I generate an apk and install the application on Android devices it works, however when I generate an aab and publish it on the playstore the map does not appear the screen goes white, I have tried several solutions and so far without success, has anyone experienced this situation or knows how to resolve it
I ensured that the Google API key is working and communicates with the server and I ensured that my SHA-1 fingerprint is the one that my app uses and the same as the Google Map API key

Does the API Key only have one restriction added? If so, you may have only included the SHA1 for the Debug build; and not the Release Build. It's a fairly common practice that different keys are used for prod vs debugging. If you are doing this, it's possible that the different API Keys come from different projects (make sure billing is enabled on them, etc).

How do you sign your applications, and how you acquired the SHA1 fingerprint that restricted your API Key with? Make sure that you are following the right steps for acquiring the correct SHA1 fingerprint based on the Android App Signing flow chart (For example, you may be using your "upload key" signature when using Google Play Signing, which would be the incorrect SHA1 Fingerprint). You can check out, in the Play Console, look for Release > Setup > App Integrity.

You can also check restricting API keys.
If you are still having problems, you can file a support case here.
